# Speed up a double for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am having an issue with the length of time it's taking to run a double for loop with an if statement within R.
In one data set I have about 3000000 rows (DF1) and in the other I have about 22 (DF2). An example of the two data frames I have are given below.

```
DF1
DateTime                 REG
2018-07-01 12:00:00      NHDG
2018-07-12 11:55:23      NSKR

DF2
StartDateTime           EndDateTime         Direction
2018-07-01 07:55:11    2018-07-01 12:01:56     W
2018-07-12 11:00:23    2018-07-12 11:45:00     E
```

I want to flag anything in DF1 when the DateTime is between StartDateTime and EndDateTime. Hence the output will be as follows:

```
DF1  
DateTime                 REG      Flag
2018-07-01 12:00:00      NHDG      1
2018-07-12 11:55:23      NSKR      0
```

The code I have used currently is:

```
#Flag if in delay or not
DF1$Flag<-0

for (i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(DF2)){
    if ((DF1$DateTime[i] >= DF2$StartDateTime[j]) & (DF1$DateTime <= DF2$EndDateTime[j])){
      DF1$Flag[i]<-1
    } else {
      DF1$Flag[i]<-DF1$Flag
    }
  }
}
```

I am more than happy for this code to be taken out of the for loops if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand properly, the value of Flag in `DF1` should be set to 1 if the DateTime is between *any* interval from `DF2`, right?
Then, the following base code would do the job:

```
DF1$Flag = sapply(DF1$DateTime, 
                  function(x) as.integer(sum(x >= DF2$StartDateTime & 
                                               x <= DF2$EndDateTime) > 0))
#              DateTime  REG Flag
# 1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG    1
# 2 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR    0
```

The idea is to vectorize the comparison: for each DateTime in `DF1` (sort of "looping" through `sapply`), you compare the value to all intervals (Start- and EndDateTime) from `DF2` and you `sum` the results: if the `sum` is greater than 0, then you have at least one line in `DF2` where DateTime from `DF1` falls between its Start- and EndDateTime. Then `as.integer` converts the boolean output of `sum(...) > 0` to `1` or `0`.

And, if you want a faster solution, using `dplyr`:

```
df1 = full_join(mutate(DF1, foo=1), mutate(DF2, foo=1), by='foo') %>% 
  mutate(Flag = as.integer(DateTime >= StartDateTime & DateTime <= EndDateTime)) %>%
  group_by(DateTime) %>% slice(which.max(Flag)) %>%
  select(DateTime, REG, Flag)
```

---

Otherwise:
There seems to be a problem with you second loop, over the rows of `DF2` (j loop): for each row of `DF1`, you compare the date to the start and end dates of successively *all* rows of `DF2`, basically overwriting every time the resulting Flag value and only keeping the result for the comparison with the very last row of `DF2`...?
In other words, `i` in `DF1$Flag[i] <- ...` does not move inside the `j` loop (and is each time overwritten).

So if you just want to compare between the min and max date range from `DF2`, you can simply do:

```
DF1$Flag = as.integer((DF1$DateTime >= min(DF2$StartDateTime)) & (DF1$DateTime <= max(DF2$EndDateTime)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
library(data.table)
DF1$flag <- as.numeric(sapply(seq(nrow(DF1)), function(x)
  DF1[x, "DateTime"] %between% c(min(DF2[x, "StartDateTime"]), max(DF2[x, "EndDateTime"]))))
#              DateTime  REG flag
# 1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG    1
# 2 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR    0
```

***Data***

```
> dput(DF1)
structure(list(DateTime = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2018-07-01 12:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 11:55:23"), class = "factor"), REG = structure(1:2, .Label = c("NHDG", 
"NSKR"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
> dput(DF2)
structure(list(StartDateTime = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2018-07-01 07:55:11", 
"2018-07-12 11:00:23"), class = "factor"), EndDateTime = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2018-07-01 12:01:56", 
"2018-07-12 11:45:00"), class = "factor"), Direction = structure(2:1, .Label = c("E", 
"W"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)) 

DF1$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DF1$DateTime)
DF2$StartDateTime <- as.POSIXct(DF2$StartDateTime)
DF2$EndDateTime <- as.POSIXct(DF2$EndDateTime)
```

Comment: This answer yields different output than the one below, and different from how I interpreted the question -- although it is a bit ambiguous. You are returning whether a date in DF1 falls between the lowest recorded date in DF2 and the highest recorded date in DF2, but I thought the target was whether a date in DF1 falls between the lowest and highest values of any particular row in DF2. I could well be wrong...

Comment: @gfgm You could be true and comparing two lists would make sense in flight statistics application, thanks! See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Could also go for `foverlaps`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF1)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime)][, EndDateTime := DateTime]
setDT(DF2)[, `:=` (StartDateTime = as.POSIXct(StartDateTime), 
                   EndDateTime = as.POSIXct (EndDateTime))]

setkey(DF1, DateTime, EndDateTime)
setkey(DF2, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)

DF1[, Flag := foverlaps(DF1, DF2, type = "within", which = TRUE, mult = "first")][
  is.na(Flag), Flag := 0][, EndDateTime := NULL]
```

This will check for every date in `DF1` if it is situated in any interval in `DF2`.

It'll also be fast, at least according to my tests. Benchmark with `sapply`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr         min           lq        mean      median           uq        max neval
     DT    4.752853     5.247319    18.38787     5.42855     6.950966   311.1944    25
 sapply 9413.337014 10598.926908 11206.14866 10892.91751 11746.901293 13568.7995    25
```

This is on a dataset with 10 000 rows in `DF1` and 12 in `DF2`.

I only ran it once on 300 000 / 22 rows, and this is what I get:

```
Unit: seconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     DT  11.60865  11.60865  11.60865  11.60865  11.60865  11.60865     1
 sapply 674.05823 674.05823 674.05823 674.05823 674.05823 674.05823     1
```

Answer (score 0):

One faster way would be to use crossing() from tidyr to cross df1 and df2, set the flag per row in the new data frame then use aggregate() to reduce the rows back down. This method assumes that there are no duplicate entries in df1. If there are, they will be combined.

```
> df1
             DateTime  REG
1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG
2 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR
> df2
        StartDateTime         EndDateTime Direction
1 2018-07-01 07:55:11 2018-07-01 12:01:56         W
2 2018-07-12 11:00:23 2018-07-12 11:45:00         E
> # Create a DF with rows for each combination of df1 rows with df2 rows
> tmp <- crossing(df1, df2)
> tmp
             DateTime  REG       StartDateTime         EndDateTime Direction
1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG 2018-07-01 07:55:11 2018-07-01 12:01:56         W
2 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG 2018-07-12 11:00:23 2018-07-12 11:45:00         E
3 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR 2018-07-01 07:55:11 2018-07-01 12:01:56         W
4 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR 2018-07-12 11:00:23 2018-07-12 11:45:00         E
> # Create a new column for the flag
> tmp$flag <- tmp$DateTime >= tmp$StartDateTime & tmp$DateTime <= tmp$EndDateTime
> tmp
             DateTime  REG       StartDateTime         EndDateTime Direction  flag
1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG 2018-07-01 07:55:11 2018-07-01 12:01:56         W  TRUE
2 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG 2018-07-12 11:00:23 2018-07-12 11:45:00         E FALSE
3 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR 2018-07-01 07:55:11 2018-07-01 12:01:56         W FALSE
4 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR 2018-07-12 11:00:23 2018-07-12 11:45:00         E FALSE
> # Drop the unwanted columns
> tmp <- tmp[,c("DateTime", "REG", "flag")]
> tmp
             DateTime  REG  flag
1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG  TRUE
2 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG FALSE
3 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR FALSE
4 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR FALSE
> # Sum all flags for a given df1 date and limit total to 1
> df1 <- aggregate(flag ~ DateTime + REG, tmp, FUN = function(x) {min(1, sum(x))})
> df1
             DateTime  REG flag
1 2018-07-01 12:00:00 NHDG    1
2 2018-07-12 11:55:23 NSKR    0
>
```

Running with many more dates and comparing against your original for loop and the sapply() method above:

```
  Original for loop method: 6.282 sec elapsed
           sapply() method:  1.65 sec elapsed
crossing() and aggregate(): 0.385 sec elapsed
```

The full script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript                                                                                                                              

library(tictoc)
library(tidyr)

# Setup: generate a lot of dates for performance comparison                                                                                         

beg <- as.POSIXct("2018-07-01 12:00:00")
end <- as.POSIXct("2100-12-01 12:00:00")
dates <- seq(beg, end, 60*60*24)

#df1 <- data.frame(c("2018-07-01 12:00:00", "2018-07-12 11:55:23"), c("NHDG","NSKR"))                                                               
df1 <- data.frame(dates, rep(c("NHDG","NSKR"), length(dates)/2))
df2 <- data.frame(c("2018-07-01 07:55:11", "2018-07-12 11:00:23"), c("2018-07-01 12:01:56", "2018-07-12 11:45:00"), c("W","E"))
colnames(df1) <- c("DateTime", "REG")
colnames(df2) <- c("StartDateTime","EndDateTime","Direction")

df1$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
df2$StartDateTime <- as.POSIXct(df2$StartDateTime, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
df2$EndDateTime <- as.POSIXct(df2$EndDateTime, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")

# Original (fixed)                                                                                                                                  

tic(sprintf("%30s", "Original for loop method"))

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df1$flag[i] <- 0
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if ((df1$DateTime[i] >= df2$StartDateTime[j]) & (df1$DateTime[i] <= df2$EndDateTime[j])){
      df1$flag[i]<-1
      break
    }
  }
}

toc()

result1 <- df1
df1$flag <- NULL

# Sapply                                                                                                                                            

tic(sprintf("%30s", "sapply() method"))

df1$flag = sapply(df1$DateTime,
                  function(x) as.integer(sum(x >= df2$StartDateTime &
                                             x <= df2$EndDateTime) > 0))
toc()

result2 <- df1
df1$flag <- NULL

# Aggregate                                                                                                                                         

tic(sprintf("%30s", "crossing() and aggregate()"))

# Create a DF with rows for each combination of df1 rows with df2 rows                                                                              
tmp <- crossing(df1, df2)
# Create a new column for the flag                                                                                                                  
tmp$flag <- tmp$DateTime >= tmp$StartDateTime & tmp$DateTime <= tmp$EndDateTime
# Drop the unwanted columns                                                                                                                         
tmp <- tmp[,c("DateTime", "REG", "flag")]
# Sum all flags for a given df1 date and limit total to 1                                                                                           
df1 <- aggregate(flag ~ DateTime + REG, tmp, FUN = function(x) {min(1, sum(x))})
# Sort the rows by date                                                                                                                             
df1 <- df1[order(df1$DateTime),]
# Reset the row names (for comparison below)                                                                                                        
rownames(df1) <- NULL

toc()

result3 <- df1

# Prove that results are the same                                                                                                                   

if (!all.equal(result1, result2)) {
  print("MISMATCH")
  stop()
}

if (!all.equal(result1, result3)) {
  print(MISMATCH)
  stop()
}

print("PASS")
```